# How to check does method systemFontOfSize(fontSize: weight:) exist in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios7, system-font

My application deployment target is iOS 7.0
I want to use method `systemFontOfSize(fontSize: weight:)` on devices with iOS 8+. iOS 7 doesn't support this method (with `weight:` parameter) and my application crashes. Specially for iOS 7 I want to set Helvetica Light font instead of SystemFont Light.

What is the best way to check it? Do I need to check iOS version or I can check the method? how?

I use swift and tried

```
if let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12, weight: UIFontWeightLight)
```

or

`respondsToSelector` method.
It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`respondsToSelector` works as expected:

```
    let font: UIFont
    if UIFont.respondsToSelector("systemFontOfSize:weight:") {
        println("YES")
        font = .systemFontOfSize(12, weight: UIFontWeightLight)
    }
    else {
        println("NO")
        font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 12)!
    }
```

And I would recommend HelveticaNeue instead of Helvetica, since the system font is  *Neue* one.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `#available` expression which is recommended in the Swift book.

```
if #available(iOS 8, *) {
    // Use iOS 8 APIs on iOS
} else {
    // Fall back to earlier iOS APIs
}
```

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2 Prerelease).” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/k5SW7.l

Comment: Good recommendation, but it works since Swift 2, that hasn't been released yet

Answer (score 0):

Checking ios version is best way

```
if NSFoundationVersionNumber > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_0 {
    // code
} else {
    // code
}
```

Comment: Chetan Prajapati, Thank you for your answer. This condition works for me with 1 correction: use NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1 istead of NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_0. I will wait some time for another opinions and accept your answer if it will be the best.

Comment: Thanks for your gentleness. :)